# Convert android preview frame to OpenCV Mat

Tags: android, opencv, camera

I'm trying to capture an image from the camera preview and convert it to a Mat object using OpenCV.
I registered the callbak method `public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)` so I receive all preview frames from the camera, but I can't get it to convert to OpenCV Mat object.

I'm currently using the following code to convert the preview `data` to a Mat object:

```
Mat previewFrameMat = new Mat(1, data.length, CvType.CV_8U);
previewFrameMat.put(0, 0, data);
```

Is this the correct way to do it ? Am I using the correct image type (`CvType.CV_8U`) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you seen how OpenCV samples do this?

```
mYuv = new Mat(getFrameHeight() + getFrameHeight() / 2, 
    getFrameWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);

....

mYuv.put(0, 0, data);
```

Full source can be found in the Android package from SourceForge or here:
http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/entry/trunk/opencv/samples/android/tutorial-1-addopencv/src/org/opencv/samples/tutorial1/Sample1View.java

Comment: Thanks. can't believe I missed it.